# How to let my laptop automatically hibernate after sleep in Windows 8.1?

Tags: laptop, sleep, power-management, hibernate

I have looked through the advanced power setting but didn't find out a method.

What I want is to let my laptop automatically hibernate after certain minutes of sleep. But if the laptop is not sleeping, it should never hibernate. I cannot figure out a way to do this. If I allow my laptop to hibernate after certain minutes, it will hibernate no matter whether it is sleeping or not.

This may sounds strange. On the one hand, I often download big files overnight. When doing this, I will keep the lib open to prevent Windows from stopping my download software. On the other hand, when I close the lib, I want my laptop to sleep. Moreover, in order to save electricity, I want it to hibernate after some time of sleep.

Comment: Windows automatically wakes up the computer from sleep and goes into hibernation when the battery level reaches critical level and if you've set the critical battery action to `Hibernate`. However can you wake up the computer from sleep at a certain time to do this? I'm not sure. Maybe you could use software that can set wake timers for this. Maybe something like [WakeUpOnStandby](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/docs.php?what=wosb)

Answer (score 7):

I believe I just found what you are looking for.  The simplest way to get there is right click your desktop > Personalize > Screen Saver > Change Power Settings > Change Advanced Power Settings > Click the + on Sleep, Then the + on Hibernate After then set your time for how long you want it to wait until it goes into hibernation after falling into it's sleep state.

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings -> Change advanced power settings -> Sleep -> Hibernate after -> Set on battery and plugged in to `Never` or `0`.

---

**1)** `Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options -> Change Plan Settings`

[image]

**2)** `Change advanced power settings`

[image]

**3)** `Sleep -> Hibernate after`, then:

Set Set on battery and plugged in to `Never` or `0`

[image]